# What is the real meaning of getValue() of BehaviorSubject?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

In API, it is written in 'Returns the current value of the Subject if there is such a value and the subject hasn't terminated yet.'

But, in this situation, which value is returned?
[image]

That is, I'm wondering getValue() returns the value subscribed and commited, or the value called by onNext().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your diagram, `subject.onNext(3)` can only be called from a different thread, as `subject.onNext(2)` has not yet returned. However, this is a violation of the reactive contract, as you are not allowed to do overlapping calls (onNext/onComplete/onError). While in many cases this behavior will not cause harm, rhere are operators like `.serialize()` that help with cringing it back to spec.

In short, in your case it's undefined.

Comment: Actually, you'd get 3 since saving the latest value internally in `BehaviorSubject` is atomic, but otherwise an overlapping call may mess up the emission state towards the subscribers and thus indeed, that is an undefined behavior. If there are no subscribers, no harm is done but still it is required to use `.toSerialized()` if there is a chance for concurrent invocation or reentrant `onNext` call from the same thread.